# Java, define a method test( ArrayList<Object> list ), but when call test(new ArrayList<String>) can't be compiled

Tags: java, generics, arraylist

I have a method:

```
public static void test(ArrayList<Object> list)
```

However, when I try to call:

```
test(new ArrayList<String>)
```

the compiler throws errors indicating no such method.

But the strange thing is, if I define another method:

```
public static void test(ArrayList<String> list)
```

compilers throws another error indicating the two methods share same signature. After this I even try:

```
if(new ArrayList<Object>().getClass().equals(new ArrayList<Resource>().getClass())){
            System.out.println("same");
        }
        else {
        }
```

The result indicates the two classes are the same.

Can someone explain it a little bit about the generic type for arraylist?

Comment: *" indicating the two methods share same signature."* You shouldn't cut out important information. Your compiler surely says that they have the same signature _after type erasure_. If you don't know what type erasure is, then google it, because it is important here.

Comment: It's because `ArrayList<String>` can't be converted to `ArrayList<Object>`. You can use `?` like this `public static void test(ArrayList<?> list)`.

Comment: You can always use a pretty simple genetic method. Here is the code: `public static <T> void test(ArrayList<T> list)`. Now you can call both `test(new ArrayList<String>)` and `test(new ArrayList<Object>)` and the same function will be invoked.